# Can not find Web.Config and System.Web.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC, recently I got the following error and could not find web.config or system.web.mvc inside my project to fix the problem. Can anyone help me with the issue?

> You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: Did you delete it? Remove it from the project?

Comment: No I din not. I can not find where is the System.web.mvc.

Comment: Did you remove/add it with (nuget) package manager? Check your /bin folder.

Comment: No ı did not. I just create my ASP.NET CORE MVC, then i wanted to add syncfusion chart to my project. by using syncfusion chart some line of code must be added to WEB.CONFIG, but i didnt find WEB.CONFIG in the asp.net core mvc.

Comment: I confused with the issue that in the app created with asp.net framework there is file called WEB.CONFIG. but it does not exist in the asp.net core mvc.

Comment: Thank you so much I used the wrong version of the syncfusion. I corrected my mistake.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as Answered. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct version of the Syncfusion components designed specifically for Asp.net Core, looks like you were using the old .NET version. https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/chart